# Invalid User Credentials in Paypal IOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

I am getting the Invalid user credentials when i am trying to log in with paypal id. I am sure i have entered the correct client ID of the live account and its working successfully on Sandbox

```
  PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: invalid_user - Incorrect username/password. Please try again。 (401) | 
    PayPal Debug-ID: b2cedad5b6842, b2cedad5b6842 [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.16.2] | 
    Details: (
            {
            "error_description" = "Invalid user credential";
        }
    ).
```

I have entered the correct live client ID. and have made the environment to production cant get this done please help here is my code below in my app delegate:

````
```
  //TODO: – Enter your credentials

        PayPalMobile .initializeWithClientIds(forEnvironments: [PayPalEnvironmentProduction:
            "**********************************-s_8AiXkLD1NA********"
            ])

    var payPalConfig = PayPalConfiguration()
````

in viewDidLoad:

```
 //=======Paypal Configuration========================================================================

    // Set up payPalConfig
    payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = true
    payPalConfig.merchantName = "Donation to Edhi"//Give your company name here.
    payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = URL(string: "“https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full”")
    payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = URL(string: "“https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full”")
    //This is the language in which your paypal sdk will be shown to users.
    payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]


    //========== un comment line below to make paypal live==============
//            environment = PayPalEnvironmentProduction
    //====================================================================


    //Here you can set the shipping address. You can choose either the address associated with PayPal account or different address. We’ll use .both here.
    payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = .both;
```

This is what i have in my function

````
    //These are the items choosen by user, for example
        let item1 = PayPalItem(name: donationTypeTxt! , withQuantity: 1, withPrice: 
    NSDecimalNumber(string: totalPaypalAmount), withCurrency: "AUD", withSku: "don-001")

        let items = [item1]
        let subtotal = PayPalItem.totalPrice(forItems: items) //This is the total price of all 
       the items
        // Optional: include payment details
        let shipping = NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.00")
        let tax = NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.00")
        let paymentDetails = PayPalPaymentDetails(subtotal: subtotal, withShipping: shipping, 
    withTax: tax)
        let total = subtotal.adding(shipping).adding(tax) //This is the total price including 
    shipping and tax
            let payment = PayPalPayment(amount: total, currencyCode: "AUD", shortDescription: "3% 
    Merchant fee is included.", intent: .sale)
        payment.items = items
        payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails
    //        var newamount: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(totalDonationAmount!) as! 
        NSDecimalNumber



        if (payment.processable) {
            let paymentViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment, 
    configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)
            paymentViewController!.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            present(paymentViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
            // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
            // empty, this payment wouldn’t be processable, and you’d want
            // to handle that here.
            print("Payment not processalbe: (payment)")
        }
```
````

Comment: Hard to be of help without the ClientID to test or easily runable code. Unless someone's able to spot something I'm not, you'll probably need to contact https://www.paypal.com/mts with the complete example, including the ClientID you are using

Comment: On iOS 13 the `-[NSData description]` method has changed significantly, rendering the PayPal fingerprint (some risk data of your account + device) invalid. They promised to deploy a fix soon. In the meantime you can swizzle `-[NSData description]` and return something similar to iOS 12. Hint: They remove all <, > and spaces anyway, so just a hex representation will do fine.